# sequence for korean, number, english & sepcial char using regex

Tags: regex

from the title itself, how to pull this thing off using regex?,
the sequence will be: Korean, Number, English & Special Characters

my regex

```
const regex = new RegExp(/^[\u3131-\uD79D0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]*$/)
```

current output:

```
abc고객센터123@@ // wrong
```

expected output:

```
고객센터123Abc@#!#%% // correct
```

advance thanks.

Comment: You can use 3 character classes `^[\u3131-\uD79D]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]*$` https://regex101.com/r/yaIVhF/1

Answer (score 0):

If all the characters have to be present at least a single time, you can use 3 character classes instead of 1 and use a quantifier `+` to match each part 1 or more times.

```
^[\u3131-\uD79D]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9vK1I/1)